# Invoke function within class method from outside the class with name the same like one method in class has

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to invoke the function within some class method from outside the class with name the same like one method in class has.

I have 3 different examples.

```
void a () { // outside the class
}

class A {
    // example 1, the same names
    void a() {
       a (); // but the outside one, 
    }
    // example 2, different list of arguments
    void a(int x) {
       a (); // but the outside one, 
    }
    // example 1, different names
    void b () {
       a (); // but the outside one, 
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference a name outside the current class, use an empty namespace operator `::`.

```
void A::a()
{
    ::a (); // calls the outside one
}
```